# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification vs. UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification

Tags: objective-c, notifications, uiapplication, uideviceorientation

What are the differences between the two and in what cases should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIInterfaceOrientation) {
UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown            = UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

}

see from the above, difference at UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft.
when device landscapeLeft,interface should rotate to right to keep content not reverse.